# Load packages automatically without `using` in Julia?

Tags: julia

When looking at files like this: https://github.com/simon-lc/Silico.jl/blob/main/examples/demo/peg_in_hole_planning.jl

The author does not call "using Silico" or "using Mehrotra" anywhere, yet calls it many times throughout the file. As someone coming from Python, I don't understand this. How does Julia know where to look for Silico without a statement like "using Silico"?

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can customize the configuration file of Julia.
For example, in Windows OS, you can go to the following path:
C://Users//.julia/config/startup.jl
Open the file and write the importing command(s) you want. E.g., `using Term` or `using OhMyREPL` and `using Statistics: mean, std` (then those functions will be available by default). Then every time you run the Julia, those packages will be imported automatically.

*Note that if this file doesn't exist in the path, you can create a file with the same name.

You can also compile the preferred packages into the Julia system image, and the Julia REPL will start a bit quicker since it does not have to parse and compile the package when loaded. The way to do this is by using [`PackageCompiler.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl). [[1](https://kristofferc.github.io/OhMyREPL.jl/latest/installation/#Automatically-start-with-Julia.)]

Comment: What is the analogy to from pkg import * in Python?

Comment: @user3180, I refer you to the Bible. [[1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Definitions)], [[2](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#What-is-the-difference-between-%22using%22-and-%22import%22?)], [[3](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Standalone-using-and-import)]

Comment: @user3180, but in short, you can say `using pkg: *`, `import pkg: *`, or `import pkg: * as f`. These are useful when the `*` is a specific function. But If you mean importing the whole functions of a package to the global scope, then `using pkg` is the best way.

Comment: Thanks - but what I don't understand is - how do I get all these functions automatically imported

Comment: For example, line here: https://github.com/simon-lc/Silico.jl/blob/ac74d90ba27b6bb47650673f3b8121a35f32c57d/examples/demo/peg_in_hole_planning.jl#L61

Comment: If I just run this command: julia '--color=yes', '--project=/root/Silico.jl', '/root/Silico.jl/examples/demo/peg_in_hole_planning.jl', '--load=/root/Silico.jl/src/Silico.jl,  it errors and says "visualize!" not found. I have to change it to "Silico.visualize!" to work.

Comment: but obviously whoever authored that file ran it differently, such that without appending Silico. in front of visualize, it still worked

Comment: so do I need an extra command line argument? or something else?

Comment: @user3180, *"how do I get all these functions automatically imported"*. **Ans:** `using Plots`, for example.

Comment: It doesn't work. In the above code, if I add "using Silico" to the top, it still errors and says "visualize!" not found. I have to modify the code, both putting "using Silico" at the top and changing "visualize!" to "Silico.visualize!"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250512/discussion-between-shayan-and-user3180).